# Solr Indexing using CSV Update UI: unique key is created as a multivalued fields errors out

Tags: csv, solr, lucene, solrcloud, solr6

I am trying to load the CSV file in the solr 6.5 collection, using the solr Admin UI. Here are the steps that I did and got the following error:

1. Created a data driven managed schema config set in Zookeeper. Changed the unique key to "MyId" (String field) instead of default id.

---

```
<uniqueKey>MyId</uniqueKey>
        ...
<field name="MyId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

2. Created collection and associated the config set mentioned above (using new Admin UI).
3. Load the CSV file using Admin UI (collections --> collection name drop down --> Documents). I have added request handler parameter of `&rowid=MyId` parameters. My CSV file has `MyId` field in it. During the load I get this error:

   `Document contains multiple values for uniqueKey field: MyId=[82552329, 1]
   at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getHashableId(AddUpdateCommand.java:168)`
4. Without changing the unique ID and just using the default `id` (with auto generated UUID) field the csv loading fine. But I need the unique id to be `MyId`

I would like to know why my key field is reported as multi-valued, my CSV does not really contain multi-valued data, it is simple comma separated numeric and string fields. Please suggest what could have gone wrong.

Note: I have made this change as well [Solr Schemaless Mode creating fields as MultiValued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730035/solr-schemaless-mode-creating-fields-as-multivalued) in the schema (does not help, as the problem is input data)

EDIT: Adding full exception trace

https://pastebin.com/raw/juRj7ZUi

Comment: What do logs say? Please show me the full log of log4j.Something tells solr to split your string into array.

Comment: added a exception trace. You are right something within probably update CSV handler to split it. But I am wondering what it could be? Though, I have not added any CSV split params in my request handler.

Comment: you could specify more params here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers and also try to use console instead of UI, the you could pass more params

Comment: I have added  [pastebin solr log with debug enabled](https://pastebin.com/raw/juRj7ZUi) as well url to the question above. Also tried split=false through the UI and i see those as well in log, but does not help it still creates a multivalued data from the csv

Comment: Another interesting thing is if i have the unique id to the default `id` field, and let the system generate the UUID using the `solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory` it is working fine. Looks like it is a bug? if we have our own unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a clue in the documentation [csv update params](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVFormattedIndexUpdates) that the issues is something to do with this param that i pass ( `&rowid=MyId`). As the documentation states that we should pass this paramater to add the line number as the id. That explains why my key (`MyId`) becomes a multi valued ([my actual key, line no.]). But then if i remove this param it was giving an error that `id` is not being populate. This means that it was expecting an id field. So added `&literal.id=1`, now everything works fine ( This is because in my schema there is required `id` field.). Thanks for helping out.